# Custom Launcher doesn't appear in Slingshot (eOS Freya)

Tags: slingshot-launcher

I created a simple desktop entry called `screen-off.desktop` which is located in `/usr/share/applications`.

The desktop entry content is based on an existing model and points to a bash script located in `/usr/bin`.

The script works fine when launching from terminal / command line.

However, after rebooting the OS, the launcher still doesn't appear in Slingshot.

I'm using Elementary OS "Freya".

How can I make it appear there?

Below is the content of my desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0                                     # version of an app.
Name[en_US]=Screen Off                          # name of an app.
GenericName=Screen Off Script                   # longer name of an app.
Exec=/usr/bin/screen-off                        # command used to launch an app.
Terminal=false                                  # whether an app requires to be run in a terminal.
Icon[en_US]=administration                      # location of icon file.
Type=Application                                # type.
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;                   # categories in which this app should be listed.
Comment[en_US]=Turn off your screen             # comment which appears as a tooltip.
```

Comment: I don't really know Slingshot but I know some GUIs require the *Category=* item to include at least one known value. Have you compared your launcher with others, which Slingshot recognizes and uses?

Comment: I thought of that and the values of the Categories variable are the same as the gnome-control-center.desktop file, i.e. `Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;` and yet, whereas the control center shows, my launcher doesn't. I'm updating my post for reference.

Comment: You could try it without [en_US]. Maybe Slingshot expects at least one entry for each entry (...) to not be i18n-ed.
Are you sure the file has the correct permissions? 
Another place to put it is `~/.local/share/applications`.